# Methods in a generator expression: gi_running, gi_yieldfrom, etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have created the following generator function:

```
>>> def file_readlines(filepath):
...     f = open(filepath, 'r')
...     for line in f:
...         yield line
... 
>>> gen=file_readlines(filepath)
>>> next(gen)
```

When I examine the methods of the generator it shows the following:

> ```
> ...'close', 'gi_code', 'gi_frame', 'gi_running', 'gi_yieldfrom', 'send', 'throw'`
> ```

`throw`, `send`, and `close` are documented in [Python Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator#generator-iterator-methods), and I imagine `code` and `frame` are similar to a stacktrace object, but what are `gi_running` and `gi_yieldfrom`? How are those used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gi_running` tells you whether or not the interpreter is currently executing instructions from the frame of the generator (`gi_frame`)

`gi_yieldfrom` is the iterator that the generator is yielding from.  It was introduced in 3.5, and you can read the enhancement ticket here: https://bugs.python.org/issue24450

```
def yielder(gen):
    yield from gen

x = range(5)  
g = yielder(x)

print(g.gi_yieldfrom) # None
next(g) # delegate to the other iterator
print(g.gi_yieldfrom) # <range_iterator object at 0x0000026A0D72C830>
list(g) # exhaust iterator
print(g.gi_yieldfrom) # None
```